# Custom error handling with showBlockPage in Function app not displaying correctly

Tags: azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c

I am facing a problem in Azure B2C where my custom error handling, implemented in an Azure Function app, is not working as expected.

This Function app is set up as an API connector, specifically for the "before creating user" event in the sign-in/sign-up (SI/SU) user flow.

The Azure Function app should trigger a `showBlockPage` response with a custom error message when a specific error condition is encountered during the sign-in/sign-up process:

```js
const existingCompany = await getCompanyByName(connection, companyName).catch(error => {
    context.log(`Error in function getCompanyByName: ${error.message}`);
    throw error;
});
if (existingCompany) {
    context.log(`Company already exists ${JSON.stringify(existingCompany)}`);
    context.res = {
        status: 400,
        body: {
            version: API_VERSION,
            action: "ShowBlockPage",
            userMessage: "Your company already exists. Please contact your administrator to be added."
        }
    };
    return;
}
```

Despite configuring the `showBlockPage` response as instructed in the documentation, Azure B2C displays the default error message instead of the custom error message:

> There was a problem processing your request. Please try again.

#### Resolution Attempts

In an effort to troubleshoot and resolve this issue, I have consulted various resources, including:

- [Azure AD B2C Custom Connector showBlockPage Response Issue on Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/953589/azure-ad-b2c-custom-connector-showblockpage-respon)
- [Stack Overflow Discussion on Azure AD B2C Custom Connector showBlockPage Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77828516/azure-b2c-custom-error-handling-with-showblockpage-in-function-app-not-displayi)
- [GitHub Issue on Azure Docs Regarding showBlockPage Response](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/105786)